# How to solve use dollar sign inside a link problem in my javascript project?

Tags: javascript

**Dollar sign is not work for my project when i was wrote inside a link**

```
//We Use To Prototypes

function Translate(word, language) {
    this.apikey = "c39d8dd7eemsh929c56378f9904ep1b7ee2jsn532547e3980a";
    this.word = word;
    this.language = language;

    //XHR object

    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
Translate.prototype.translateWord = function (callback) {
    
    //Ajax

    const endpoint = 'https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2/languages?key=${this.apikey}';

};
```

**I appreciate any help available!

i was trying to insert information to form and automatically to pull information from api and yeah i was adding to jquery to my project so this is not the problem**

Comment: You need to use backticks instead of single quotes to make a template literal.

Comment: Never share private API keys online

Answer (score -1):

Instead of quotes, wrap your string in backticks `` ` `` ([Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

```
const endpoint = `https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2/languages?key=${this.apikey}`;
```

Comment: I already used  back quote  so it did not working. But what did you mean exactly . Where should i put back-quote

Comment: Enclose the string with it, copy and past the code in my answer.